# run Gazebo in ROS indigo in Virtualbox with libGl and openGl errors

Tags: ros, gazebo, virtualbox, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
Error [gazebo.cc:220] Waited 11 seconds for namespaces. Giving up;  
libGL error: pci id for fd 10: 80ee:beef, driver (null);  
OpenGL Warning: Failed to connect to host. Make sure 3D acceleration is enabled for this VM;  
libGL error: core dri or dri2 extension not found;  
libGL error: failed to load driver: vboxvideo;  
Error [Node.cc:90] No namespace found;
```

Like I said, first run Gazebo, I see some error like that. any problem?
I just follow steps in http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_installing   which is   "Test that stand-alone Gazebo works"

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203740/run-gazebo-in-ros-indigo-in-virtualbox-with-libgl-and-opengl-errors/) by [crazymumu](https://answers.ros.org/users/21710/crazymumu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 214 on 2015-02-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) on 2015-02-25**:
Never tried on a virtual machine. I know that virtualbox has a lot of issues with OpenGL. Have you tried on a native lunix ?

**Comment by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) on 2015-09-28**:
Parallels 10 has no issues running gazebo 5 or higher. Also did you enable 3D acceleration in your VB settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

if you can run headless, try unsetting environment variable DISPLAY, and run gzserver only.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2015-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1